# Using Twitch API for authentification inside a Chrome app

Tags: php, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, twitch

I'm trying to do something but i don't really know if that's possible:

I have website where users can only login using their Twitch account via the Twitch API. When they're doing it the first time, it creates their account and when they do it again, it logs them. And when they're logged in, a session variable in PHP is set so i can check on every page if the user is logged in or not.

The thing is i want to have a chrome app that can get informations about the authentified user and displays them on it (it has to be a separated window).

But i'm facing the following issue: i cannot use twitch api on my chrome app because it needs a redirect uri which i can't provide because, well, it's a chrome app. (and i don't really know much about them, i tried webviews and iframes but no success)

Comment: You should take a look at [`chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow). You can provide a redirect URI.

Comment: I don't really get it:

can i call this function on my javascript background script using something like document.getElementById("button").onclick ?

details.string is supposed to be the uri i call when i went to have the twitch log in form ? and the second parameter is a function i should use to treat the data returned by the twitch api ?

Comment: Why don't you try it? If you fail, you could post your best attempt as an edit to this question and ask for further help.

Comment: Okay, i succeeded :D Thanks for your help mate

Comment: It'd be excellent if you shared your solution as a self-answer.